# Generate a string of arbitrary size appending other strings: how?

Tags: c, string, append

I'm having a couple of problems with the dynamic construction of a string of unknown size. Trying to explain my problem I wrote this small code (pseudo-C-code) that is supposed to generate a `finalstring` appending each time a new string:

```
char *finalstring;
while (/* condition */) {
    char *tmp = get_new_string();
    finalstring = strcat(finalstring, tmp);
}
printf("%s\n", finalstring);
```

At each iteration `get_new_string()` will get a different string that I want to add up to `finalstring`. Each string will always be of a fixed `STRSIZE`, so at each iteration `finalstring` can grow of `STRSIZE` `char`s.

How can I really implement this in C? I'm not sure about the use I should do of `malloc`s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Generate a string of arbitrary size appending other strings: how?

Keep track of the *string length* and re-allocate as needed for the new string.

```
char *final_string = NULL;
size_t final_len = 0;  // size_t is the best type for "size" math and array indexing
while (/* condition */) {
    char *tmp = get_new_string();
    size_t tmp_len = strlen(tmp);

    // Allocate enough for the length of both parts and a \0   
    char *s = realloc(final_string, final_len + tmp_len + 1);
    if (s == NULL) {
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    final_string = s; 

    // As code knows the strings lengths, 
    // easy enough to use fast memcpy to concatenate....
    memcpy(final_string + final_len, tmp, tmp_len + 1);
    final_len += tmp_len;
}

if (final_string) {  // If needed in case loop body never executed.
  printf("%s\n", final_string);
}
free(final_string);
```

---

This answer does not take advantage of "Each string will always be of a fixed `STRSIZE`".  That is a marginally beneficial condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can `reallocate` (using `realloc`) to the `oldsize + new string length` to get the variable where you can concatenate the new string. That will solve the problem for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    char *finalstring = NULL;
    size_t oldsize = 0;
    size_t i=0;
    char s[][10]={"AA","BB","CC","DD"};
    size_t sz = sizeof s / sizeof s[0];
    while (i < sz) {
        size_t newsize = strlen(s[i]);
        size_t templen = newsize + oldsize ;
        if(oldsize == 0) templen++;
        char *temp  = realloc(finalstring , templen );
        if(temp == NULL){
            perror("realloc failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        finalstring = temp;

        if(oldsize == 0){
            strcpy(finalstring,s[i]);
        }
        else
            strcat(finalstring,s[i]);
        oldsize = z;
        i++;
    }

   printf("%s\n",finalstring );
   free(finalstring);
   return 0;
}
```

For the first string one more space is allocated to keep the `\0`. Successive strings don't require that as previous `\0` will be overwritten. Instead of `s[i]` you will use the string that you will get as return from the `get_new_string()` function.